# how to edit model data using django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i'm new to django so i'm sorry for my newbie question 

i have a model and i need to let user edit data inside it using django forms or any other way.
[image]

look at the image above , i want to show this form ready populated with the data and let user update  it.
what is the best way to do this ?

EDIT : here is my views.py code

```
def exam_Edit(request,examName,number=0):
    numner = int(number)
    number = int(number)
    questionNo = int(numner)
    Myexam = models.Exam.objects.get(name = examName)



    QuestionsAll = models.Question.objects.filter(exam = Myexam)

    myQeustion = Question.objects.filter(exam = Myexam)[nextQuestion]

    answer1 =  models.Asnwers.objects.filter(question=myQeustion)[0]
    answer2 =  models.Asnwers.objects.filter(question=myQeustion)[1]
    answer3 =  models.Asnwers.objects.filter(question=myQeustion)[2]
    answer4 = models.Asnwers.objects.filter(question=myQeustion)[3]


    # HERE IS MY PROBLEM : the line below creates a form with a data but it doesn't save it to the save object     
    form = QuestionsEditForm(initial = {'questionText':myQeustion.__unicode__() , 'firstChoiceText':answer1.__unicode__(),'secondChoiceText':answer2.__unicode__(),'thirdChoiceText':answer3.__unicode__(),'forthChoiceText':answer4.__unicode__()})

    if request.method =='POST':
        #if post 

        if form.is_valid():
            questionText = form.cleaned_data['questionText']
            Myexam = Exam.objects.get(name = examName)
            myQeustion.questionText = form.cleaned_data['questionText']



            answer1.answerText = form.cleaned_data['firstChoiceText']
            answer1.save()

            answer2.answerText = form.cleaned_data['secondChoiceText']
            answer2.save()

            answer3.answerText = form.cleaned_data['thirdChoiceText']
            answer3.save()

            answer4.answerText = form.cleaned_data['forthChoiceText']
            answer4.save()

 variables = RequestContext(request,     {'form':form,'examName':examName,'questionNo':str(nextQuestion)})
 return render_to_response('exam_edit.html',variables)
```

please help

Comment: What part of http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms was confusing?  Can you be more specific?  Can you post your code?

Comment: Why don't you post some of the code you already have? This is as simple as returning a "Question" model object with fields that you populate with default text.

Comment: Just a heads up, but the last 2 lines of your code aren't indented.

Comment: @S.Lott: Nothing. However, there is nothing in there that answers the question.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `ModelForm`, use the `instance` keyword argument, and pass the model you are updating.

So, if you have `MyModel` and `MyModelForm` (the latter of which must extend `django.forms.ModelForm`), then your code snippet might look like:

```
my_record = MyModel.objects.get(id=XXX)
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_record)
```

And then, when the user sends back data by POST:

```
form = MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=my_record)
```

Incidentally, the documentation for `ModelForm` is here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: This cannot be the best answer. The logic that you just described is implemented by the admin module, with permissions and all. There must be a way to use that on the frontend.

Comment: @oneloop, even if you were to implement an edit data feature on the frontend, you need to send data to the backend to update. I would assume you would create an entire view and pass work with the request from there