# Editing existing entries in Django forms

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-views

My problem is similar to [how to edit model data using django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023421/how-to-edit-model-data-using-django-forms), but I'm not able to solve it. 
I would like to get an form with prefielled fields and to allow user to edit them.
I believe my problem is in views.py file, but unfrotuntely I'm not able to solve it.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField()
    warranty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 
from items.models import Item

class EditItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('product','quantity', 'price', 'purchase_date', 'warranty', 'comment')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^show_all/$', 'items.views.items'),
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'items.views.item'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', 'items.views.edit'),
)
```

**edit.html**

```
<form action="/items/edit/" method="post" class="form horizontal well">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <imput type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Aktualizuj">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from items.models import Item
from decimal import Decimal
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from items.forms import EditItemForm
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditItemForm(request.POST, instance=request.item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/items/show_all/')

    else:
        form = EditItemForm(instance=item)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('edit.html', args)
```

Above code is resulting this message:

> TypeError at /items/edit/1/
>
> edit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item_id'

Can you please help me?

Django 1.6, Python 3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've imagined an attribute called `request.item`. There's no such thing. You need to get the item from the database, via the ID passed into the function as alecxe showed.

```
def edit(request, item_id):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditItemForm(request.POST, instance=item)
```

Comment: There is one remaining problem. Because of the fact that I'm passing "return render_to_response('edit.html', args)" my edit.html file is not able to be populated by {{ item.id }} in <form action="/items/edit/{{ item.id }}/" (...) . How to get this id and put it to html file?

Comment: Well, that should be obvious: add the item (or even better, the id) into `args`. But actually, you don't even need to do that: you're posting to the *current* URL, so you can just do `action="."`.

Answer (score 1):

`edit()` view should allow a keyword argument `item_id`:

```
def edit(request, item_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, this solves this warning. But it still doesnt work. I believe there is problem with "instance". Is there any expected flow of those arguments?

Comment: @user3093247 ok, what is happening?

Comment: I believe there is problem with "instance". Is there any expected flow of those arguments?