# Django - Get previous form filled data when I come back to form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm newer to Django. When I return to a form I would like it to be filled with the info that it was previously filled with by the user. I noticed that when I got into Django admin and add content to the models I can see previous info that has been added before. Is there a way to do this outside of Django Admin? Is there a way to do this for images as well?

Thank you

Models:

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['content', instance.user.username, filename])


class Content(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    terms = models.CharField(max_length="256", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views:

```
@login_required
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = Content(user=request.user,
                               logo=request.FILES.get('logo'),
                               image1=request.FILES.get('image1'),
                               terms=request.POST.get('terms'))
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/portal/register')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    return render(request, 'portal/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Forms:

```
class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):

    logo = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    image1 = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    terms = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['user', 'logo', 'image1', 'terms']
```

Edit:
I was pointed to an answer that gave a little insight on how to solve the problem. The answer pointed to

```
my_record = MyModel.objects.get(id=XXX)
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_record)

form = MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=my_record)
```

Can someone point me in the direction on what to use for id to grab the info already in the model?

Edit 2:

This code now returns the info in the model, but when I input new data and save I load the page again and the new content isnt saved and shows the what was originally there. Any idea on how to show the new data?

```
@login_required
def register(request):

    info = Content.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=info)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = Content(user=request.user,
                               logo=request.FILES.get('logo'),
                               image1=request.FILES.get('image1'),
                               terms=request.POST.get('terms'))
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/portal/register')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm(instance=info)

        return render(request, 'portal/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023421/how-to-edit-model-data-using-django-forms, this should answer your question here.

Comment: Looking over the answer you pointed me to. How do I properly add id to grab the instance? I added an edit to my question. Thank you

Comment: id = request.user.id

Comment: Could you help me with the new problem? I have the form returning the data, but I cannot save new data to it .