# Django UpdateView: cannot get form fields to show database values

Tags: python, django, django-views

I found multiple answers to this same questions but unfortunately, I can't seem to figure it out :(

The form has a drop-down list for the 'subcategory' field in my model 'PhysicalPart', the values of the 'subcategory' field are updated dynamically upon the form creation (using a 'category' parameter).

Unfortunately, I can't get the drop-down to show all subcategories **AND** have the one from the database selected at the same time. I can't seem to retrieve the 'short_description' value either from the database.

It used to work before I learned about UpdateView class and decided to use it instead...

Any insight on how-to workaround my problem would be appreciated!

forms.py

```
class PartForm(forms.ModelForm):
subcategory = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

class Meta:
    model = PhysicalPart
    fields = ['subcategory', 'short_description']
```

views.py

```
class PartUpdate(UpdateView):
model = PhysicalPart
template_name = 'part_update.html'
form_class = PartForm

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Load model instance
    self.object = self.get_object()
    # Load form
    form = super(PartUpdate, self).get_form(self.form_class)
    # Populating subcategory choices
    form.fields['subcategory'].choices = SubcategoryFilter[self.object.category]

    # Check if form valid and save data
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return redirect('part-list')

    # Update context before rendering
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['part_id'] = self.object.pk
    context['part_category'] = self.object.category
    context['manufacturing_list'] = self.object.manufacturing.all()

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

html

```
<form action="{% url 'part-update' pk=part_id category=part_category %}" method="post" style="display: inline">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">Type</br>
        {{ form.subcategory }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">Short Description</br>
        {{ form.short_description }}
        </p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'part-list' %}" style="display: inline">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show your models ?

Comment: @BleuBizarre I don't think this issue has anything to do with my model, it is just a bunch of CharField ('subcategory' too).

Comment: To be able to understand your model.Why is your subcategory not a ForeignKey?

Comment: At the moment you force a choice to the filter, are you sure this is working ? Maybe try with some random value to double check if it’s not the reason you are no seeing nothing

Comment: @BleuBizarre "Why is your subcategory not a ForeignKey?" > I'm not familiar with ForeignKey concept yet, I'll read about it (still in the learning phase).

"At the moment you force a choice to the filter, are you sure this is working ?" > It looks like it is, see my own answer to my original request.

Comment: ForeignKey > allows you to have a OneToMany relation basically it will store the ID of the wanted Category in the database but when you ask for it in django it will directly be the object related to this ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I did not differentiate the "GET" versus the "POST" calls in the **UpdateView** class, I was trying to do everything in the *post()* method. It took me a while to figure it out but now I think it's clear.
I originally used the *get()* method but I realize that *get_context_data()* was better suited as it automatically loads most of the context (eg. the instance and the form), instead of having to do everything from scratch in the *get()* method.

Scrubbing through the code of the UpdateView class [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/), it also seemed necessary to add *ModelFormMixin* into the declaration of the PartUpdate class so that the *get_context_data()* method automatically loads the form associated to the target model/instance (else it looks like it won't do it).

Here is my updated views.py code:

```
class PartUpdate(UpdateView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = PhysicalPart
    template_name = 'part_update.html'
    form_class = PartForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('part-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Load context from GET request
        context = super(PartUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Get id from PhysicalPart instance 
        context['part_id'] = self.object.id
        # Get category from PhysicalPart instance
        context['part_category'] = self.object.category
        # Add choices to form 'subcategory' field
        context['form'].fields['subcategory'].choices = SubcategoryFilter[self.object.category]

        # Return context to be used in form view
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get instance of PhysicalPart
        self.object = self.get_object()
        # Load form
        form = self.get_form()
        # Add choices to form 'subcategory' field
        form.fields['subcategory'].choices = SubcategoryFilter[self.object.category]
        # Check if form is valid and save PhysicalPart instance
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are trying to edit an instance. This is how you do it in Django, it should autopopulate your inputs with the proper values :

```
my_record = MyModel.objects.get(id=XXX)
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_record)
```

More details on this answer : [how to edit model data using django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023421/how-to-edit-model-data-using-django-forms)

If your models are properly done (with relations) you shouldn't need to provide the choices for the Select.

Comment: Outside of the UpdateView class, what you said worked fine. I have tried it here too, however if I replace "form = super(PartUpdate, self).get_form(self.form_class)" with "form = PartForm(request.POST, instance=self.object)" I get the same result...